# Problems converting/testing for a string in python

Tags: python

I have a basic program that I am trying to make fool proof, and not come up with an error when the wrong type of data is entered.

Here is my code (Python 2)

```
   choice = raw_input("Enter a number")
   choice = int(choice)
   print choice + 1
```

However, when I enter a letter, it tries to convert it into a integer and fails. What would be the best way to overcome this?

Comment: What do you want it to do when you enter a letter?

Comment: You need to put that in `while` and `try|except`. `while` would run until user enter integer value, `try|except` would try to convert input to `int`

Comment: Try the ```isdigit()``` function => https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit